# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in xerces parsing

Tags: xml, arrays, xerces

I do not know where the problem is... Help and Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8192
```

at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:543)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1619)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1657)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1740)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
 at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
 at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:277)
 at myPackage.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:39)

In the mainclass, code framework as below:

```
SAXParserFactory sf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();   
SAXParser sax = sf.newSAXParser();   
sax.parse("english.xml", new DefaultElementHandler("page"){   
public void processElement(Element element) { 
// process the element
}
});
```

The XML file is huge 4G, and full of text, I need to parse the file and process the text.

Currently, I did nothing the process part, just wanted to print them out in the console. Then OOB...

Comment: Can you post the contents of MainClass so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: Also post some of the XML you are trying to parse, please.

Comment: <page>
  <revision>
    content text
  </revision>
  ...
  <revision>
  </revision>
</page>
...

Comment: From the stack trace your application is clearly not picking up Xerces 2.9.1. com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.* is Sun's fork of the Apache codebase in their JDK (5 or 6). I have no idea whether they have fixed this problem.
The Apache Xerces packages are org.apache.xerces.* and you would see those in the stack trace if you were using Xerces 2.9.1.
So what shall I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try printing out the error message that goes along with that stack trace.  You can do that by adding a call to `System.err.println(e.getMessage())` where `e` is the exception.  The message should give you the index that was trying to be accessed.

**If the index is negative then there is most likely an integer overflow.**  If that's the case, you should file a bug report with Xerces.  It's possible that Xerces wasn't designed to handle files that large.

Comment: where to catch the exception, i.e. add System.err.println(e.getMessage())?

I used public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {} at the moment.

Comment: From the stacktrace, It appears that the invalid index is 8192.  I suspect it's a Xerces bug.  Even if it were invalid UTF-8 in the file Xerces shouldn't throw like this.

Comment: Yeah, I also seen a thread here, http://marc.info/?l=xerces-j-user&m=120452263925040&w=2. Seems the same problem (they used version 2.7x), and haven't got a clue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is ten years old, but I am answering this because this Stack Overflow post is the top result on Google and anyone else who runs into this might need a fix, as I did just today.

**Yes, it is a bug in Xerces and as of March 2020 it is STILL NOT FIXED.** It is relatively straight-forward to work around, however.

The bug has nothing to do with the file size. Xerces has issues with certain 4-byte UTF-8 character sequences. It has been patched multiple times over the course of years. (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080085)

Depending on your platform, your Java environment may assume a default encoding of UTF-16. When Xerces hits one of these four byte sequences on a UTF-16 platform, you get the exception trace shown.

Fortunately, this is easy to fix. One easy fix the bug report suggests is to convert all 4-byte UTF-8 characters in the input file into numeric character entities. The other "more correct" way is to explicitly specify your encoding... even if it was already specified in your XML schema, specify it anyway as part of your input stream.

e.g. If you are accessing Xerces via SAX, **do not call `SAXParser.parse(filename, handler)`** the way it shows in most tutorials. Instead, you need to create your own InputStream like so:

```
final SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
File file = new File(filename);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");                      
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");                      
saxParser.parse(is, handler);
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and specifying the encoding did not help. I used [Woodstox](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox) instead. The transition was very easy. I only had to change one line of my code:

```
import com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory;

WstxInputFactory xmlInputFactory = WstxInputFactory.newInstance();
```